# What is the intended audience for this site?

Tags: discussion

Most of the questions so far seem specifically geared towards players in the class A - class C range (1400-1900).  Is this by design, or more just due to the random sampling of the first 20 questions?

Answer (score 6):

The [original proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7551?phase=definition) talks about  serious players and enthusiasts of chess, however, I don't think we are bound by this definition.

Just like [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), I think it's better to leave the target as broad as possible, from newbie players to Pros. What should be "regulated" are the questions.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would like to see, at a minimum, the level of discussion that occurs at other sites, such as ChessPub.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the idea as that once it becomes popular we can have GMs, IMs and FMs to join the site and help out on the expert level questions. (I have stated that in the original proposal Announcements/Comments)
Yes we need to start ranking such questions which are tough as expert-level or something similar, but again newbies may mark simple questions as expert-level to gain attention, so moderation will be required, any ideas??